# Проблема достижения консенсуса в p2p

Tags: python, сокет, p2p, blockchain

**Помогите решить задачу**

1. есть два-три компьютера (далее ноды), которые обмениваются через сеть информацией (p2p)
2. Каждая нода получает свои данные через браузер от клиента
3. полученные данные должны синхронизироваться между нодами и записываться в одинаковом порядке в базу
4. после чего отправлять друг другу подтверждение консенсуса

**Как я это вижу (писать буду на python):**

1. создаем соединение через socket между нодами
2. ноды договариваются, какая следующая будет запись
3. если одна из нод получает данные от клиента, отправляем данные второй ноде

**Но как решить проблемы:**

1. если ноды одновременно получат данные от клиента, как они договорятся, какая запись будет первая записана в базу?
2. и что лучше использовать потоки threads или asyncio

*Может есть какие-то решения готовые или статьи? Не могу ничего найти(*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы указали в тегах blockchain, то можно использовать его.

Ответ на ваш первый вопрос. Сделайте каждой записи свой id. Например:

```
id = hash(prev_id + record_data)
```

Где `hash` - ваша любимая хеш-функция, `prev_id` - айди предыдущей записи, `record_data` - данные текущей записи.

Как будет достигаться консенсус. Предположим, в нашей сети нет злоумышленников (иначе задача будет очень сложной). Тогда при поступлении одновременно 2 записей, которые ссылаются на одну и ту же предыдущую запись, ноды могут выбирать ту, в которой меньший id. При этом желательно отослать ответ в сеть, что другая запись с таким-то id невалидная, и нода, которая создала эту запись, должна заново вычислить ее id (ссылаясь уже на другую запись) и заново разослать в сеть.

При этом ноды будут удалять со своей базы данных невалидные записи, и вставлять их в правильном порядке.